# Read XML child node Attribute on VBA with oDOC

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I have a list of different animals (following XML file),
**some** of the animals have children,
I wrote something that print all children animal names
it won't work 
it say "object dosen't support this property or method"
If I would replace this line : 
`Set list =oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/animal/cat[(@ID)=""17""]")`

to that one: 
    `Set list = xDoc.SelectNodes("/animal/cat[(@ID)=""17""]")` 
my code works perfect , but I can't replace it because other method required that list will defined like that :
    `Set list = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/animal/cat[(@ID)=""17""]")`

any idea, to solve my problem?

note:not every animal have a child, and if they have, some will have 4 children some 3 etc.. (I can't know how many children animal can have)

VBA (using XDoc):

```
Sub test()

    Dim xml As String
          xml = ("C:.....\example2.xml")
    Dim xDoc As DOMDocument
    Set xDoc = New DOMDocument

    Dim list As Object

    Dim attr As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim node As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim childNode As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim oDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60


   oDoc.validateOnParse = True

  'xDoc.Load xml 
  'oDoc.Load xml

  ' Set list = XDoc.SelectNodes("/animal/cat[(@ID)=""17""]")
  ' Set list = oDoc.SelectSingleNode("/animal/cat[(@ID)=""17""]")

  For Each node In list <-- **this line will not work!!**
        If (node.HasChildNodes) Then

            For Each childNode In node.ChildNodes
            Set attr = childNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("Name")
                 Debug.Print attr.Text
            Next childNode
        End If
    Next node

End Sub
```

XML:

```
<animal>
           <dog ID="16" Name="Lucy"/>
           <cat ID="156" Name="Chloe"/>
           <cat ID="17" Name="GAL">
                 <child ID="173" Name="Tigger"/>
                 <child ID="1256" Name="Angel"/>
                 <child ID="256" Name="Peanut"/>
           </cat>
           <cat ID="18" Name="Charlie">
                 <child ID="173" Name="Smokey"/>
           </cat>
  </animal>
```

Comment: You are kidding us. You really ask why Select**Single**Node does not return a node list but a **single** node?

Comment: Use the latest Xml library I think you're confusing things there.  As @Axel Richter points out the method name is self-descriptive.   `SelectNodes` returns an interface of type `IXmlDomNodeList` whereas `SelectSingleNode` returns an interface of type `IXmlDomNode`, you can only put the former in a `For Each ... In` loop.

Comment: @AxelRichter  so if i understand you right you suggest to just define again the list and i don't have other option..

Comment: No, I suggest using `SelectNodes` if you want a node list and using `SelectSingleNode` only if you want a single node. Both methods are usable wit `DOMDocument` as well as with `DOMDocument60`. But `list` can only be one kind of object either a node list or a node.

Comment: ok, thanks for your answer