# get Attributes name item of the first node from list of nodes

Tags: xml, vba, excel

the following code will print  this:
"GAL"

is there any option to print the same output using  "xDoc.SelectNodes"
but without the 'for each node in list'?
because i know that the parent will be only one node, so seems to me silly that I have to use this- 'for' and also define new variable ('node')
 thanks for any help !

VBA:

```
    Dim xDoc As DOMDocument
    Set xDoc = New DOMDocument
    xDoc.Load ("C:\....\example2.xml")
    Set list = xDoc.SelectNodes("/animal/cat[(@ID)=""17""]")
    Dim attr As IXMLDOMAttribute
    Dim node As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim childNode As IXMLDOMNode

   For Each node In list
        Debug.Print node.Attributes.getNamedItem("Name").Text
    Next node
```

XML:

```
<animal>
           <dog ID="16" Name="Lucy"/>
           <cat ID="156" Name="Chloe"/>
           <cat ID="17" Name="GAL">
                 <child ID="173" Name="Tigger"/>
                 <child ID="1256" Name="Angel"/>
                 <child ID="256" Name="Peanut"/>
           </cat>
           <cat ID="18" Name="Charlie">
                 <child ID="173" Name="Smokey"/>
           </cat>
  </animal>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you opened a new question, this is revisiting yesterday's [Read XML child node Attribute on VBA with oDOC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242293/read-xml-child-node-attribute-on-vba-with-odoc)

Anyway, if you really have a problem with the loop running one item (frankly, I don't know why) then you can inspect the `length` of the `list` object.

```
If list.length=1 Then
    List.item(0).Attributes.getNamedItem("Name").Text
Else
    'Do the loop
End If
```

Can't you just add a comment saying you expect the for loop to run over one single item?

Rewriting your code

```
Sub Tst()


    Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    xDoc.Load ThisWorkbook.Path & "\example2.xml" '<---- my path is different

    Dim oSingular As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
    Set oSingular = xDoc.SelectSingleNode("/animal/cat[(@ID)=""17""]")

    Debug.Print oSingular.Attributes.getNamedItem("Name").Text

'    Set List = xDoc.SelectNodes("/animal/cat[(@ID)=""17""]")
'    Dim attr As IXMLDOMAttribute
'    Dim node As IXMLDOMNode
'    Dim childNode As IXMLDOMNode
'
'    For Each node In List
'        Debug.Print node.Attributes.getNamedItem("Name").Text
'    Next node


End Sub
```

Comment: yeah I already ask about it, still didn't found any answer for that,
I'm blowing my mind how to merge two different codes.
the first mission i have is to display names of cat with ID 17 (Tigger,angel, peaunut) and i know how to do it with xDoc , and in other place of code i also want to print name of cat with Id="173" and this i also doing with oDoc, i'm desperately tryng to marge them, i don't want to load the doc twice, all the answer and i still not get it what should i do

Comment: I don't understand why you have two documents.  Please edit question to show what Tools References you have active.  And as yesterday, I suggest you stick to the latest library Microsoft Xml 6.0.  Also edit your code to fully qualify your `Dim` statements so `Dim foo as MSXML2.DomDoucment60`

Comment: about your answer how you Do the singular?

Comment: @David: let me tell you that SelectSingleNode calls SelectNodes and then calls .item(0) to get the first item.

Comment: Thanks god! this is finally solve my problem, I wrote your solution and add  .text , that was what i ask for...

Comment: Debug.Print list.Item(0).Attributes(1).Text

Comment: when you use it you don't need the loop , and i think that will be an answer to my question , thanks for helping

Comment: if i want to print it but i don't know the number of attribute, you know if i can search attribute by name and not by number ? something like that?
 Debug.Print list.Item(0).Attributes("Name").Text

Comment: Debug.Print list.Item(0).Attributes.getNamedItem("Name").Text